# IE 10 browser Issue

Tags: asp.net

net(V 4.0)  in my web application asp link button is not working in IE 10 but its working all other version of IE. please can someone help in this. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Welcome to SO, please try to be more specific, and provide code and more info; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Thats a problem with browser definition files.

Comment: So throught the below answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/16272799/2131245

Hope it will help u!

Answer (score 0):

Thats a problem with browser definition files that shipped with .NET 4. You just need to update the browser definition files.