# Link Button not working with IE 10

Tags: asp.net, cross-browser, windows-server-2008

I have an problem related to Link Button Click event in asp.net on Internet Explorer 10.Link Button click event is not firing. It shows the javascript error

```
SCRIPT5009: '__doPostBack' is undefined
```

I have **Windows Server 2008 Standard Without Hyper-v(6.0, Build 6001)** on my system. I tried to fix this problem by [Patch](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088) provided by Microsoft but that didn't work.I hope you understand my question very well and will give meaningful answer's.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Problem occurred cause of:**
There is a bug in the browser definition files that shipped with .NET 2.0 and .NET 4, namely that they contain definitions for a certain range of browser versions. But the versions for some browsers (like IE 10) aren't within those ranges any more. Therefore, ASP.NET sees them as unknown browsers and defaults to a down-level definition, which has certain inconveniences, like that it does not support features like JavaScript.

I also had same problem,I followed this article, and I'm sorted. Go through below link, It would help for sure.

[Fix](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9"

meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8"

meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"

Comment: Would give this answer +2 if I could! Thank you, save me alot of time!

Answer (score 0):

Use compatibility meta tags for ie10 which makes your application to run in ie9

i.e.use meta tags for backward compatibility