# IE 10 issue with postback

Tags: asp.net, .net, internet-explorer-10

I have a ASP.NET 2.0 site which i upgraded to ASP.NEt 4.0. When we test it on IE 10 it has issue for following client side line. It says SCRIPT5022: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Input string was not in a correct format.

```
<a id="ctlLogin" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ctlLogin$ctl00&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Logoff</a>
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

If you've already applied the HotFix as imran001 suggested, have you rebooted the machine/server the HotFix was applied to?

Comment: Yes i have restarted server

Answer (score 0):

I believe .NET 4.0 may not be enough. [Many issues with MS Ajax and IE10](http://codecorner.galanter.net/2013/05/01/solution-for-ie10-error-script5022-sys-argumentoutofrangeexception-value-must-be-an-integer/) where resolved in 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through below [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16272799/2131245):

Hope it will help you!